# QTextDocument single border for table

Tags: qt, report, qtextdocument

Making report's in QT without html, i've got such problem as multiple border in table -
each cell got self border.

```
QTextTableFormat tableFormat;
tableFormat.setCellPadding(5);'
tableFormat.setHeaderRowCount(1);
tableFormat.setBorderStyle(QTextFrameFormat::BorderStyle_Solid);
tableFormat.setBorder(1);
```

...

Changing setBorder(x) gave no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to set cellSpacing to 0, also better view for solid bordered table gives such as printed in 2 line:

```
tableFormat.setCellSpacing(0);

tableFormat.setBorderBrush(QBrush(Qt::SolidPattern));
```